# z-index property does not work

Tags: html, css

I want to set that `in put textbox`'s location on initial condition header `div`. But that textbox is getting hidden under initial condition div. 
**Are there any alternative to z-index**. I have attached my css also.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="initialCondHdr" class="initialCondHdr">Demo Experiment</div>
<div id="archiveTable_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
    <label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" style="width:220px;height:30px;" />
    </label>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#initialCondHdr {
    color:#043751;
    font-family:calibri;
    font-size:19px;
    line-height:42px;
    position:relative;
    text-indent:15px;
}
.dataTables_filter {
    float: left;
    left: 119px;
    margin: 12px 0 22px 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    top: -20px;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: why are you floating it to left?

Comment: It works when I copy/paste the code.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: Nothing i was just trying all option.. i think i left it by mistake....Actual css is
  .dataTables_filter{
        left: 119px;
        margin: 12px 0 22px 12px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: right;
        top: -20px;
        z-index: 5;}

Comment: its working fine.. check this.http://jsfiddle.net/sxW69/#&togetherjs=Tbo02I7wk6

Comment: what you mean "initial condition div"??

Comment: @Quentin : In my case its not working...Actually i'm using dataTable.js ,this textbox is part of that only.
This Text box is part of second template which gets rendered in the div which is placed in first template.

Comment: @Ksa — If it isn't working for you, but it is working when I copy/paste the code in the question, then your question doesn't include whatever is causing the problem and you need to fix that!

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do but I **think** you are trying to lay the input on top of the first div.

That being the case, you will have to change the HTML structure and adjust the positioning of your input as follows:

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/hvCBE/)

**Revised HTML**

```
<div id="initialCondHdr" class="initialCondHdr">Demo Experiment
    <div id="archiveTable_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
        <label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" style="width:220px;height:30px;"/>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Revised CSS**

```
  #initialCondHdr{
        color:#043751;
        font-family:calibri;
        font-size:19px;
        line-height:42px;
        position:relative;
        text-indent:15px;
        color:red; /* visual reference only */
}
    .dataTables_filter{
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        opacity:0.5; /* visual reference only */
        top:0;
        text-align: right;
        z-index: 1;
}
```